# ListView ColumnWidthChanged Event gets fired 'without reason'

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a listview and an event handler for the ColumnWidthChanged event, which stores the new column sizes in a config file every time the user changes something.

I've created flags for every process that is changing the columns internally for being able to only react on user inputs.

Still this event gets fired at program start ( once for every column in the listview ).

The call stack only shows the event, 'external code' and the main 'program.cs'.

I just can't find out where the event is getting triggered from. Any ideas?

Comment: If the form that is on is your main, then it's calculating the width of every column at startup in preparation of displaying. I would wait to add your event handler until the ?Loaded? event. I don't remember which one it is that is fired after it's finished rendering.

Comment: Try wiring to the ColumnWidthChanged event in the [Shown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: I tested the form's 'load' event and added the listviews event handler there. But the listview event wasn't fired at all then.

Comment: Put it into the Shown event. Before that, add the current code to your question so I can see how you're manually wiring to the event. Also include the method you're wiring.

Comment: That worked THX ! Still this is strange behaviour. I also have a DataGridView in the same form, also reacting to column width changes but that event doesn't get fired at startup...

Comment: I'll add an answer and try to explain some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to put the code where you wire up the `ColumnWidthChanged` event into the [Shown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx) event of your form.

What is happening is that the ListView is taking up physical space on the form, so as it is being built, it has to calculate the size of each column. Therefore, as it is populating the data into them, those columns get resized once they have the data. That would be why it is firing once for each column before it is even displayed.

As for why it is not firing on the DataGridView, I am thinking that the size of the object is what is added to the form. It would wait to calculate the size of each of the columns until after the DataGridView is already added to the Form. It's a little unintuitive behavior, but that appears to be what is happening from the results you're seeing.