# c# winforms - catch user's ColumnWidthChanged event?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to catch user changing the width of columns in DatagridView control. The ColumnWidthChanged event is getting fired when the form is build ([as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026945/listview-columnwidthchanged-event-gets-fired-without-reason)) but this is not what I need, I need only when the user do it.

Looks simple but I can't find the right event - and I'v tried everything that looks related.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: if we can check whether mouse down is in pressed state, then can we infer that this is user driven action

Comment: Of course this is the right event. If you need you can ignore it as kishore suggests: `if (Control.MouseButtons == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.None) return;`

Comment: @TaW To be fair, some controls have events that are more geared towards user-caused changes, or "programmatic" changes. For example, the `SelectionChangedComitted` event on a `ComboBox` fires when the list opens, an item is selected, and the list closes -- compared to the `SelectedIndeChanged` or `SelectedValueChanged` events which will fire if you coded `myCmb.SelectedIndex = 0`

Comment: Hi, the ColumnWidthChanged event is fired after the user release the mouse key, so in any way what @TaW wrote would return true and doesn't help to find it the user did something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found:

```
    private void Form_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView.ColumnWidthChanged += dataGridView_ColumnWidthChanged;
    }

    private void dataGridView_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        // it's the user who clicked!!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void FastObjectListView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, ColumnWidthChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FastObjectListView foListView = sender as FastObjectListView;
    if (foListView.Focused == true)
    {
        //To do
    }
}
```

I used focus property to make sure it's changed by the user. I looked up into all the properties but didn't find anything else better.